# xpage ssjs onpage load or lookup

Tags: xpages

I am new to xpage.  I have an xpage that is bound to a document in a database.  I need to prepopulate several fields in the xpage from couple of other databases.  Some of the prepopulated fields get saved to the document and some are display only.

My question is should write ssjs on page load to pull this information or create datasource and bind the xpage fields to this dsn (particularly for display fields). Which is the best practice and good for performance?

Comment: As far as I can say this is a "unanswerable question", because in my opinion the "best practise" is the minimum development effort ;-) There are a lot of other parameters to check before these question could be answered correctly: Are the informations cachable? What about the other databases? Are they on different servers, or other systems? What about the performance of the different data sources? Is there a database which is slower than the others? Why not using Java beans? And many, many more...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use datasources. Especially if you can initialize them easily (have its UNID at hand).
Don't forget to set "Ignore request param" to true for side datasources.